# Assignment Problem

Tags: algorithms

Given $N$ jobs and $M$ tasks, assign $K$ jobs to $K$ tasks where $K\leq\min(M,N)$ so that the max_cost out of $K$ jobs is minimized.

Can you help me with algorithm for the problem. I have tried brute force but I doesn't work for large inputs. Can we use Dynamic Programming here?

Comment: How are the costs given (e.g. on edges, on vertices, etc.)? Do you want to minimize $\sum_i \mathrm{cost}_i$ or perhaps $\max_i \mathrm{cost}_i$?

Comment: Cost on edges. I want to minimize max(cost) and not sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Have you heard about the [Hopcroft-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithm?
- Let's call a number $C$ admissible if there exist a solution $S$ such that
  $$C = \max_{e \in S} \mathrm{cost}(e).$$
- Can you check if given $C$ is admissible and reconstruct any such solution if it is?
- If you don't know $C$, you can use binary search.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I just solved the problem and yes with Hopcroft-Karp. I did some research and found that algo. Thanks any way...